# click a tab direct to new activity with tab

Tags: android, android-tabs

I have a screen with 2 tabs in the bottom, when the second one be clicked it will direct to another new screen with 2 tabs in the bottom as well, but tabs in first screen will stack in new screen, see the image and  you can see.

1st screen

```
setContentView(R.layout.tabs);   
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.setClass(this, CardDetailActivity.class);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("CardDetail").setContent(intent));
intent.setClass(this, CardTransTabActivity.class);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Transactions").setContent(intent));
```

2nd screen

```
setContentView(R.layout.tabs);
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.setClass(this, UsageTransactionHistoryActivity.class);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("FarePayment").setContent(intent));
intent.setClass(this, ReloadTransactionHistoryActivity.class);
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Reload").setContent(intent));
```

[image]

I don't want tabs be stacked in second screen, how to do that?

Comment: is that your real code? Using the same Intent twice and only call setClass will result that the class for `tab1` will be the same as the class inside the `tab2` intent! Also `getIntent()` will return the Intent which STARTED that Activity

Answer (score 0):

Beside the problem I mention inside my comment that is expected behavior. TabHost is deprecated and should be avoided. You should look at the new [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) or implement Custom-Buttons that starts Activitys.